# Is it safe to connect HDMI from a 110 V device with a 220 V device?

Tags: voltage, transformer, step-down, hdmi

I have a PC powered by a 110 V outlet (220 V-110 V step-down transformer) and a monitor powered by a 220 V outlet. Would it be safe to output my display to the monitor via HDMI?

Comment: Yes, it's safe (unless something is HORRIBLY wrong with the transformer or either device).  HDMI signals are low voltage and standardized by the HDMI specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe.

In consumer equipment, such as your PC and monitor, the HDMI signals are produced from an safety-isolated low-voltage supply, based around a transformer. The actual mains voltages are irrelevant to the HDMI interface.

Any concern would be for the safety ground, which is connected to the HDMI shield - the metal surround on the connector plug and socket. However, both of your equipment are on the same 220 Vac supply and using the same local ground so they are fine to use. By which I mean they have no more ground loop problems that a 220 V PC and 220 V monitor would have off of the same plug sockets.